# Problems with QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qlineedit, qtreewidget

Good morning, I am learning about programming and GUI in Qt c++ and I have some doubts:

[image: picture here]

Let's suppose you have this GUI shown in the picture. No worries about how has it been created. It has:

- QTreeWidget
- QLineEdit
- QPushButton1
- QPushButton2

How would you make the following things?

1. When clicking on a name or in a value, to make that only the value of this row appear in the QLineEdit

   In the next example, I have been able to show the name or the value, but I only want the value to be shown, even if the name has been clicked.

   ```
   void MainWindow::on_treeView_activated(const QModelIndex &index)
   {
       QString val = ui->treeView->model()->data(index).toString();
       ui->lineEdit->setText(val);
   }
   ```
2. If I change the value of the QLineEdit and then click the QPushButton1, the QTreeWidget should be updated with this new value.
3. If I click the QPushButton2, save "the names = the values" into a .txt file
4. (FUTURE) I want to have these 3 point clear first. Then, my goal is to make the same with this picture:

   [image: picture2 here]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: one question per post please.

Comment: Learn [Qt model-view programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) and [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)